# My laptop shuts off when I unplug it while using Windows 10, but is fine when I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I recently just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a different laptop and set up root, home, and swap partitions after using gparted to resize the Windows partition, 'cause Windows wasn't allowing me to resize as much as I needed it using its management tool.

After I installed a number of softwares and updates, I realized the root partition wasn't going to be enough so I went ahead and tried to resize it again using a live USB. Worked fine for a while, then it shut off twice.

When I went on to use my Windows, it randomly shuts off when it's not plugged in. It works fine if it's plugged in. I thought it was either the battery or the hard disk but then when I tried to unplug it while using Ubuntu, it didn't turn off.

I didn't watch a tutorial that time when I installed Ubuntu, I thought I had enough experience from previous installs. That may have been wrong.
I think I may have messed up with partitioning.
I'm also planning on just swapping out the hard disk for an ssd, do you think it would solve it? By swapping the hardware and having a fresh Windows install?

Comment: Using gparted to override windows tools usually not a good idea.  Have you checked windows power settings?  Re-installing does usually fix our messes.  It will also give you time to make proper size partitions instead of having to adjust them after.  If hard disk is good can place it in external case and have extra storage.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I had a feeling that using gparted was a bad idea. I think re-installing windows would be my best bet.

Comment: When reinstalling can size windows partition instead of it taking whole drive(might use gparted before installation to make NTFS partition)